# Analytic result of the expectation of a quadratic under a Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

In "http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse/static/slides/lec-10.pdf", the instructor says that LQR works in stochastic dynamics in the same way as it works in deterministic dynamics, and mentions that the expectation of a quadratic under a Gaussian has an analytic solution.

What's the analytic result of the following expectation?
$$
E_{X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\Sigma)}\left[X^TAX+X^TB+
C\right]
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$X^TAX+X^TB+C=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}X_iX_j+\sum_{i}b_iX_i+C$$
Therefore
$$
\mathbb E\left[X^TAX+X^TB+
C\right]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}X_iX_j+\sum_{i}b_iX_i+C\right]
$$
$$
=
\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\mathbb E[X_iX_j]+\sum_{i}b_i\mathbb E[X_i]+C
$$
Here
$$
\mathbb E[X_iX_j] = \sigma_{ij}+\mu_i\mu_j,\quad \mathbb E[X_i]=\mu_i.
$$
Finally,
$$
\mathbb E\left[X^TAX+X^TB+
C\right]=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\sigma_{ij} + \mu^TA\mu + \mu^TB+C 
$$
As Did noted in comment below, the answer can be rewritten as follows:
$$
\mathbb E\left[X^TAX+X^TB+
C\right]=\textrm{tr}(A\Sigma) + \mu^TA\mu + \mu^TB+C. 
$$

Comment: The first term in the final result is $\mathrm{tr}(A\Sigma)$.

Comment: Thank you, @Did !

Comment: Thanks for your solution, @NCh and Did :-). I've added the context as you suggest. Sorry about that.